# why i getting lifetime error when use Rust + PyO3

Tags: rust, lifetime, pyo3

I have simple function like this:

```rust
fn get_python()-> (PyResult<&'static PyModule>, &'static Python){
    let indicators_file = fs::read_to_string(concat!(
    env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"),
    "/python_lib/base.py"
    ))
        .expect("Should have been able to read the file");

    let (module, &py) = Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let module = PyModule::from_code(py, &indicators_file, "indicators", "indicators");
        (module, &py)
    });

    (module, &py)
}
```

And i want to use this fn like `rust let (mod, py) = get_python().expect("strange error");`
but I get an error missing lifetime specifier [E0106] at "&'static Python"
What i must do? Im beginner in the rust lang

i tried to google and modify code

Comment: What does it say if you make that `Python<'static>`?

Comment: "What i must do? Im beginner in the rust lang i tried to google and modify code" rust is *not* a language conducive to randomly throwing shit at the wall in the hope something sticks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the Python interpreter out of the closure as it is only valid with the closure method.

This is because Python has to acquire a lock for the gil and releases it at the end of the execution of the closure method.

Just call your code you want to execute by either passing a function / closure to your method or call it within the function.

Comment: but creating a module requires 200 m s, which is a lot for me, how can it be accelerated?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to return the lock guard in the first place? Why are you returning a module? Why doesn't the caller provide the gil witness?

Comment: Can you reuse the module, then just move it up the call stack and reuse it